# Why do spheres randomly go out of draw range with orbitControl() on in p5.js?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

When I use this code, and zoom out using scroll down on the mouse, the sphere goes out of draw range at a certain point. How can I fix that problem to make the sphere NEVER go out of existance?

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400,WEBGL);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  orbitControl();
  sphere(1000,24,24)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In p5.js, a canvas has a limit, a boundary. Also, the shapes that gets drawn inside that boundary have a draw limit as well. In your code, the ellipse just "goes out of existence" because that limit was passed by the camera, but by making the shape larger, you increase the amount of Z axis you can zoom out (if that makes sense). I don't know if there IS a way ti keep that from happening, but I do know that the "draw limit" can be extended by making the shapes larger.

Hope that helped! Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for the help! I really understand how this works now!